Error: `headers` was called outside a request scope | Next.js
I'm using Clerk version 5.1.4 and Next.js 14.2.3, and got the following error when calling the auth() function in a server component:
Clerk: auth() and currentUser() are only supported in App Router (/app directory). If you're using /pages, try getAuth() instead. Original error: Error: headers was called outside a request scope. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-dynamic-api-wrong-context
I've made sure I'm using App Router (/app directory), but the error still occurs. What else should I check or configure to fix this issue? Is there a way to ensure that auth() is called properly in the Next.js server environment?
    export const BoardList = async () => {
      const { orgId } = auth();

      if (!orgId) {
        return redirect("/select-org");
      }

      const boards = await db.board.findMany({
        where: { orgId: orgId },
        orderBy: { createdAt: "desc" },
      });

      return (
        <div className="space-y-4">
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
            {boards.map((board) => (
              <Link
                key={board.id}
                href={`/board/${board.id}`}
                className="group relative aspect-video bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover bg-sky-700 rounded-sm h-full p-2 overflow-hidden"
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${board.imageThumbUrl})` }}
              >
                <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-black/30 group-hover:bg-black/40 transition" />
                <p className="relative font-semibold text-white">{board.title}</p>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

I have placed code using auth() in server component (BoardList) to query data from database and handle server side logic but it doesn't solve the above problem.

Did you find a solution? I also have the same issue
